# Passing Data in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new in android developing and currently studying about passing data in each screen and I found that there is more than 2 method, and can you guys tell me when I can use navigation argument, Shared ViewModel, dependency, and persistent storage when passing data?

Best method for passing data in jetpack compose

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args You can find it here

Comment: How about the other method is there any specific advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on the requirements or the scope where that particular data or functionality is needed. I am trying to give you some examples for each kind of ways to pass data.

**1. ViewModel:** If there is any list or some common functionality then you can use `ShareViewModel` to access them at different scope like a `buttonClickListener` or some other functionality.

**2. Nav Arguments:** Suppose you have to pass an `id` for let say Chat. Then you can fetch that `id` in the `composable`/`component` and then can set the UI particular for that chat. Use in case when you clicked some item and need to show complete item on new screen.

**3. Dependency:** Suppose you want a common instance of `SharedPreferences` or anything else like database instance then you can use it for `singleton` instance. Or if you want to achieve loose-coupling then use can also use `Dagger-Hilt` for the **dependency injection**.

**4. Persistance Storage:** It can be used to store something locally for example `cache`. You can use `DataStore` or `SharedPreferences` for it.

There are some more ways also to pass data like `Intent`, `ApplicationClass`, etc.

**5. Intent (DeepLinks):** Use this when you have to pass data between activities *(can be implicit intent as well)* like sharing some image, sending some data, etc. Then you can fetch them inside your `activity` using `getIntent().getExtras()` function. This functionality can also be achieved using `navGraphs` by implementing `deepLinks`.

**6. Application Class:** You have to create a singleton instance for you application class then you can set some data to use it throughout your application be accessing the same object. Android provide same instance if you use `applicationContext as MyApplication` in kotlin and then no create to handle the singleton manually.

So the best way is only up to you according to the requirements.